# Método Get no funciona con button

Tags: php, html5

Estoy creando una página web con PHP y HTML, al usar un  no me permite enviar una variable con método get (Y eso que el button esta encerrado en un ), tal vez pueda ser que estoy combinando dos metodos el GET y el POST, pero en principio pienso que no deberia fallar, ya que si escribo el codigo sin el  funciona perfectamente todo, el problema al parecer es precisamente el uso del . Codigo:

```
<div class="iniciar">
        
        <form method="POST" action="PHP-procedimiento/respuesta.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="item-ini">Titulo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Titulo" name="titulo" required></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td class="item-ini">Descripción</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><textarea placeholder="Descripción" name="mensaje" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                
                <?php
                //recibimos el ID del tema al que vmaos a responder.
                $id = $_GET["id"]; 
                
                
                echo "<tr><td>"; 
                echo "<a href='PHP-procedimiento/respuesta.php?idt=$id'><button type='submit'>Enviar</button></a>";
                echo "</td></tr>";
                ?>   

            </table>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: El error indica un índice `idt` no definido, pero en el código que nos muestras solo se observa `id`, ¿dónde tratas de usar al primero?

Comment: @BetaM Lo uso en otro archivo .PHP, de hecho, si envió la variable mediante solamente un <a> todo funciona perfectamente, pero si uso un <button> deja de funcionar.

Comment: @BetaM aquí el verdadero problema está en el uso del <button>, pero es que es necesario usarlo para poder enviar datos de un formulario, no sé si hay otra forma. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Lo que muestras no es un formulario realmente... no veo las etiquetas `<form>` ... `</form>` por ningún lado.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que pasa es que si están las etiquetas "form" pero no vi necesario enseñarlas, todo el tema del "form" y el "table" está, aquí el problema es cuando Coloco un <button> entre <a>, cuando hago eso, la variable no se envía, pero si solo uso <a> la variable sí se envía.

Comment: Cuando hay problemas con formulario conviene poner el código completo, **en forma de texto, NO de imagen**, así podremos revisarlo. Con que cometas errores de sintaxis o no pongas las etiquetas `name` adecuadamente,  los formularios no se enviarían. Por otra parte, **debes decidir cómo se enviarán los datos**, si todos juntos con el `form` (cuando el mismo se envíe) o aparte, en forma de enlace. Estás mezclando conceptos, de ahí viene la confusión y los errores en tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya edité la publicación y añadí todo el código. Gracias por la ayuda. ¿Qué podría hacer si necesito enviar dicha variable que recibi mediante un formulario?

Comment: @SantiagoPadillaZambrano Todo codigo es escrito, te recomiendo leer [ayuda-edicion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para que puedas poner tu codigo correctamente

Comment: Pon el código como texto pulsando en [edit]. El código como imagen es difícil de analizar y de reproducir para pruebas si hiciera falta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, déjenme ponerme en ello, el sistema de stack me confunde un poco, lo resuelvo y les aviso.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo solvente, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no está bien así:

```
echo "<a href='PHP-procedimiento/respuesta.php?idt=$id'><button type='submit'>Enviar</button></a>";
```

Si observas, el formulario tiene una propiedad `action` que ya tiene esa URL. Si además de los otros valores del formulario quieres enviar el valor de `$id`  asociado con una clave `idt` simplemente tienes que crear un elemento (`input`  u otro) con el `name="idt"` y ponerle el valor de la variable. He declarado ese `input` como `readonly` asumiendo que no debería poder modificarse, si no es así le quitas esa propiedad.

Por otro lado, el `button` se deja solo, si etiqueta `a`, para que al pulsar en él se envíe todo el formulario que, supongo, es lo que quieres aquí.

Es importante que quede claro que, cuando se envía un formulario, lo que ocurre es que se crea un array asociativo, donde las claves son los `name` de los elementos, y los valores son los `value`. Significa que, el input cuyo nombre es ahora `idt` irá asociado con el `value` del mismo, que es la variable `$id` que asignamos. Y lo mismo pasará con los otros elementos que tengan `name` y `value`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="iniciar">
        
        <form method="POST" action="PHP-procedimiento/respuesta.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="item-ini">Titulo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Titulo" name="titulo" required></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td class="item-ini">Descripción</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><textarea placeholder="Descripción" name="mensaje" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                
                <?php
                //recibimos el ID del tema al que vmaos a responder.
                $id = $_GET["id"]; 
                
                
                echo '<tr><td><input readonly type="text" name="idt" value="'.$id.'" /><td></tr>"; 
                echo "<tr><td><button type='submit'>Enviar</button>";
                echo "</td></tr>";
                ?>   

            </table>
        </form>
</div>
```

En cuanto al código PHP, usa en la lectura el método según lo que pusiste el formulario. Lo digo porque se aprecia el uso de `$_GET` en tu código, pero en el formulario declaraste el método como `POST`. Ese uso mezclado funciona a veces, pero a veces no y no es coherente enviar por un método y leer por otro.

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo, eres un pedazo de genio. Saludos y muchísimas gracias.